# Laravel Mockery phpunit error: Unresolvable dependency resolving

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, phpunit, laravel-facade

Fairly new to testing but can't this test with a facade to work correctly. The code itself is working correctly. Just want the test to work also :')

The serviceprovider:

```
<?php

class ServiceProvider extends AbstractServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->singleton(RedisHashManager::class, $this->hashManagerSingleton(...));
    }

    /**
     * @return array<int, string>
     */
    public function provides(): array
    {
        return [RedisHashManager::class];
    }

    private function hashManagerSingleton(Application $app): RedisHashManager
    {
        return new RedisHashManager($app->make(Factory::class), 'cache');
    }
}
```

The facade

```
<?php

class RedisHashCache extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor(): string
    {
        return RedisHashManager::class;
    }
}
```

The code to test:

```
<?php

trait HashTrait
{
    protected function getHashes(array $keys, array $fields): Collection
    {
        $keys = collect($keys)->mapWithKeys(static function ($key) use ($fields) {
            return [$key => $fields];
        })->toArray();

        $fieldCount = count($fields);

        return RedisHashCache::getHashes($keys)
            ->reject(static function ($data) use ($fieldCount) {
                return count($data) !== $fieldCount;
            });
    }
}
```

The test itself:

```
<?php

class HashTraitTest extends TestCase
{
    use HashTrait;

    public function testGetHashes(): void
    {
        RedisHashCache::shouldReceive('getHashes')
            ->once();

        $this->getHashes(['canidae:canis:lupus:lycaon'], ['color', 'food']);
    }
}
```

(I removed the namespaces and uses, they are in the real code)

When I run the test, I got the following error: `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [ <required> string $connectionName ]] in class AbstractRedisManager`

The AbstractRedisManager is extended by the RedisHashManager and requires 2 parameters in the construct: a RedisFactory as the first one which is resolving correctly and a simple string which is giving the error.

The second parameter hasn't got a default value, when I set a default value it's working correctly. But I don't know if that is the correct/only fix I've got for the problem.

Hopefully someone could help me out?

Comment: First of all, I have never seen an anonymous static function in my 15 years of experience with PHP, this is the first time, why are you using them (I am curious now)? Second, I cannot fully remember how a Facade works right now, but I think it skips the definition found on a service provider when mocked, because that is literally what Mocking is doing, it tries to run the constructor of the class being mocked (in this case, you do not get an instance from the `singleton` definition when mocked).

Comment: The anonymous static function is some kind of micro optimization. The class isn't binded to the function.

I indeed found out that is wasn't getting the instance from the singleton. But that raises the question how it knows to get the correct class for the facade. Kind of magic.

Comment: If `RedisHashManager` does really exist and is extending a class, then it will be found. Differnet would have been if you defined an alias instead of a class on your singleton, for example `'redisHash'` and in your facade you are returning `redisHash`, then it would be not found and it would literally need to run the singleton definition to get something back, maybe that works for you